# Windows Phone 7.1 GPS

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, gps, location

I am trying to use a string that has a location(i.e. a book store read from an xml file) and then gives you directions from your current location to reach that particular book store. I am unsure as to how to do this. I believe it requires bing maps, but I am wondering if anyone has any code that performs a similar operation. Maybe you need specific coordinate points to be read in from the XML file? Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rely on `BingMapsDirectionsTask` to accomplish that easily. Following is an example on how to show direction from current location to a book store location :

```
var directionTask = new BingMapsDirectionsTask();
var bookStoreCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(Double.Parse(latitudeStringFromXml, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                                            Double.Parse(longitudeStringFromXml, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
directionTask.End = new LabeledMapLocation("book store name", bookStoreCoordinate);
directionTask.Show();
```

You can search with keyword "windows phone 7 BingMapsDirectionsTask" to get further information.